# How do you auto-increment a list column in SP AFTER an item is inserted?

Tags: auto-increment

We're building a training program into SP, and we have a list of individual 'Learning Objects' that contains a title, a Description, Duration, etc. . . Pretty standard stuff.

However, we also want to suggest the order in which these Learning Objects should be accessed and completed. It looks like this:

[image]

So, a new student should complete the ***Welcome to Chris*** item first, then the ***Products on LM.com*** etc.

The problem is . . . what happens when we need to insert an item? I.E. Maybe we develop a new module that needs to be completed between the ***Welcome from Chris*** and the ***Products on LM.com*** modules? This item would become the new ***Suggested Order 2***, but then I would need everything starting with the *existing* ***Suggested Order 2*** to increment by 1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with a Power Automate Flow:

[image]

My Filter query in the 'Peek Code' area is:

```
"$filter": "(Suggested_x0020_Order ge '@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Suggested_x0020_Order']}') and (ID lt '@{variables('newItemID')}')"
```

And my 'Apply to Each' code for the column in question is:

```
add(items('Apply_to_each')?['Suggested_x0020_Order'], 1)
```

Power Automate is pretty awesome! Although this takes about 30 seconds to run all the way through.